# Cannot get index.html from a NUnit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nunit, blazor, blazor-client-side

I try to write end-end test with NUnit and Asp.net-core-hosted Blazor WebAssembly Application.

I created a new project with 3.1.7 template.
Then I just add a NUnit project and write simple test.

```
private const string serviceUrl = "https://localhost:50200";
private HttpClient _httpClient;

[OneTimeSetUp]
public void Init()
{
    var arguments = new string[0];
    var builder = Program.CreateHostBuilder(arguments);

    _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    builder
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w => w.UseUrls(serviceUrl))
        .Build()
        .Start();
}

[Test]
public async Task HomePageResponcesOk()
{            
    var requestUrl = serviceUrl;
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

[Test]
public async Task ApiResponcesOk()
{
    var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/WeatherForecast";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

I've changed nothing else.

I get the next result

```
Test                        Duration  Error Message
HomePageResponcesOk Failed  45 ms     Expected: OK   But was:  NotFound 
ApiResponcesOk      Passed  364 ms
```

What I do wrong?

I can point out, that it works fine in more early Blazor WebAssembly versions.

---

I have added yet two other tests

```
[Test]
public async Task AppCssResponcesOk()
{
    var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/css/app.css";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}

[Test]
public async Task WebAssemblyResponcesOk()
{
    var requestUrl = $"{serviceUrl}/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js";
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

They return the same result `Failed  45 ms     Expected: OK   But was:  NotFound`.

I assume that `app.UseStaticFiles();` does not work how I expect. May it be true? How fix it?

---

So, when test project started, the backend does not know where *wwwroot* is. It can be fixed with `UseWebRoot()`.

```
builder
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w =>
    {
        w.UseUrls(serviceUrl);
        w.UseWebRoot(@"..\..\..\..\BlazorApp2\Client\wwwroot");
    })
   .Build()
   .Start();
```

All tests passed successfully, except `WebAssemblyResponcesOk()`. It is beacause of  the file placed in another directory `\BlazorApp2\Client\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\wwwroot\_framework`.
If I add second `.UseWebRoot()` then just first one be cancelled.

---

Ok, I dive into ASP.Net Core source code with the debugger.

There are next facts.

If run backend project, then `_fileProvider` field in the class `StaticFileMiddleware` gets a complex value with next structure:

```
CompositeFileProvider-- ._fileProviders
                               |                  
                               +-- NullFileProvider
                               |
                               +-- StaticWebAssetsFileProvider-- .InnerProvider
                                                                       |
                                                             PhysicalFileProvider
                               |
                               +-- StaticWebAssetsFileProvider-- .InnerProvider
                                                                       |    
                                                             PhysicalFileProvider
```

One`PhysicalFileProvider` is targeted to *wwwroot* in the source code, another to *wwwroot* in the `/bin`.

If run the tests, `StaticFileMiddleware` `_fileProvider` gets simple `PhysicalFileProvider` target as `UseWebRoot()` argument is. If I return to version without `UseWebRoot()`, `NullFileProvider` will be set there.

Now I can realized what was hapenning on the start. But I still don't know what exactly has an effect on a StaticFileMiddleware file provider. The class construcor gets the value with a injection of `IOptions<StaticFileOptions>`.

Where should I set a breakpoint for catching DI registration of this type?

Comment: Is it working from the browser?

Comment: @DIlshodK. If I launch backend project "BlazorApp.Server" directly it works perfectly. If I would run tests in debug mode, and go to **https://localhost:50200** I will get  the browser 404 message. If I go to **https://localhost:50200/WeatherForecast** I will see the json result.

Comment: It is working on me. Can you share your project on Github?

Comment: From the top of my head - did you try using [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver)? It takes an `IWebHostBuilder` as a constructor parameter, and has a `CreateClient()` method which returns a `HttpClient`.

Comment: Also, [here's a good read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory) on testing web applications.

Comment: @Grx70. "For testing SPAs, we recommended a tool such as Selenium, which can automate a browser." a phrase from your link. Selenium would be my next step to test Blazor SPA, if the home page responses from NUnit. `CreateClient()` is not what I need.

Comment: @Grx70 I have tried `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().CreateClient()`. All tests passed.

Comment: Another recommendation for you to try: [Alba](https://jasperfx.github.io/alba/) is a testing library for ASP.NET Core - it runs the web project and can test request/responses. It requires a lot less work that Selenium to get working. I use it for testing APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I've copied *.StaticWebAssets.xml files from `...\Server\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` to `...\NUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`
2. I've added `UseStaticWebAssets()` into backend launch code.

   ```
   builder
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(w =>
    {
        w.UseUrls(serviceUrl);
        w.UseStaticWebAssets();
    })
   .Build()
   .Start();
   ```

All of the tests passed. Debugger shows `CompositeFileProvider` injection with same structure as when backend launched manual...

I've setup copying of these files in build events

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy ..\Rest\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\net5.0-windows\*.StaticWebAssets.xml .\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\net5.0-windows\*.*" />
</Target>
```

It a pity, that I cannot realize how implement auto-generation StaticWebAssets.xml in a test project.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your received response i.e. ***“NotFound”***, my first guess would be that the path being created for fetching that particular file might be incorrect. If I was to debug that I’d probably try a few overloads of the [“MapFallbackToFile”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfilesendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapfallbacktofile?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_StaticFilesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions_MapFallbackToFile_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Routing_IEndpointRouteBuilder_System_String_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_StaticFileOptions_) function. Ones that require an explicit path (absolute or relative) or other properties. After a bit of hit and trial, you might be able to find the respective file.

Another thing you can do to speed up the debugging process is that you can programmatically check the current working directory and use that as a point of reference to construct the accurate file path needed. This can be done using the following command:

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`

A very commonly faced error is that often our program is running in the build directory (e.g bin/debug/..) and our required file (e.g. css or image) file is not present there, hence, we encounter such issues. This is one way to go about solving this problem.